# Левую панель нужно сделать ниже

Tags: css

[image: html]

[image: Это css]

Левая панель должна уходить вниз на 2000 пикселей ниже чем  навигационная панель, а они на одном уровне. и что бы текст из page-text был правее левой колонки и ниже навигационной панели

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)